# Find last occurance of string in csv file with reference to column in file

Tags: php, csv

Good Day All
I have a csv file that I would like to read from and calculate total times.
The only times I need would be if the last column time would differ with more than 2 minutes.
The file would look something like:

```
L1,is,2.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:07:46
L1,is,4.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:09:46
L1,is,6.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:11:46
L1,is,8.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:13:46
L1,is,10.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:15:46
L1,is,2.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:19:49
L1,is,4.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:21:49
L1,is,6.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:23:49
L1,is,8.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:25:49
L1,is,10.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:27:49
L1,is,16.2,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:34:02
L1,is,18.2,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:36:02
L1,is,20.2,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,shop,18:38:02
L1,is,2.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,bridge,21:45:26
L1,is,4.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,bridge,21:47:26
L1,is,6.0,mins,LATE,for,Arrive,at,bridge,21:49:26
```

EDIT: Changed the csv file example to the actual file.
I can get the all the values into an array, but I only need the value if the time in the last column increment is more than 2 min from the first.
So typically I would hope to see:

```
L1 is late 30.2 min at shop and 6 min late at bridge.
```

Any Help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Your solution works thanks alot, I changed it to only look at the 3rd column. Thanks again

Comment: great! sorry the little harsh comment, was totally confused :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I thought you wanedt to calculate the total time, and made answer out of that :)

To just find the last time (or whatever) in a incremental produced CSV, based on a certain column value :

```
$locations=array();
if (($handle = fopen('your-csv-file.csv', "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $location=$data[count($data)-2];
        $time=$data[count($data)-1];
        $locations[$location]=$time;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

`$locations` now hold all locations present in the CSV, and the value of the last occurence,

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($locations);
echo '</pre>';
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [shop] => 09:02:00
    [bridge] => 09:06:00
)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps alot, what I need is the lat occurance of the integer 4 mins late and not the time stamp itself.

Comment: I have changed the question, hope this makes more sense. Is there a way to filter the results? Thanks